# Is it possible to digitise on nanites in Unreal Engine 5?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

I am not a programmer, but I need information from an UE5 expert to see if I can develop an educational game.

1. I need to use high-resolution photogrammetry 3D assets as props within the game which will be converted to nanite objects.
2. I need to be able to digitise directly on the nanite objects.
3. I believe I will need to turn on the collision mesh to enable this, but I am not sure if the coarse resolution of the collision mesh will allow me to do what I want to do.
4. Can UE5 be programmed so that the collision mesh is fine enough for me to do this?
5. I also have some geometric measurement tools (such as a compass) that need to be written into the game and this is written in C++. Can this be done?

I'm a complete outsider and not a programmer, so your reply in understandable language would be most appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a site for programmers to ask questions about programming. Even if this was split into individual questions, they's still be off-topic. Since you're not a programmer, you'll need to hire one.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.